# Vertical alignment of \multirow using fraction as subscript

Tags: multirow, booktabs

I am using booktabs and multirow to build my table. Below is my sample code,

```
\usepackage{multirow,booktabs}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{lllllllr} 
        \toprule
        \multirow{2}[3]{*}{$\#$} & \multirow{2}[3]{*}{$f$} & \multirow{2}[3]{*}{$J$} & \multirow{2}[3]{*}{$Re_{\frac{3}{4}}$} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$w = 8$} \\
        \cmidrule{5-7}
        & & & & $\Delta t_{x}$ & $\Delta t_{y}$ & $\Delta t_{z}$\\ 
        \midrule 
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

and I am getting below table. Notice the Re is little above J and this is due to fraction as subscript. Is it possible to position Re same as J??

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either *smash* the fraction, or use `\sfrac`. I cropped the `\cmidrule` as it looks nicer (in my opinion):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{array, multirow,booktabs}
\usepackage{xfrac}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{*{6}{l}r}
    \toprule
    \multirow{2}[3]{*}{$\#$} & \multirow{2}[3]{*}{$f$} & \multirow{2}[3]{*}{$J$} & \multirow{2}[3]{*}{$Re_{\smash[b]{\frac{3}{4}}}$} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$w = 8$} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){5-7}
    & & & & $\Delta t_{x}$ & $\Delta t_{y}$ & $\Delta t_{z}$\\
    \midrule
\end{tabular}
\vskip1cm
\begin{tabular}{*{6}{l}r}
    \toprule
    \multirow{2}[3]{*}{$\#$} & \multirow{2}[3]{*}{$f$} & \multirow{2}[3]{*}{$J$} & \multirow{2}[3]{*}{$Re_{\sfrac{3}{4}}$} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$w = 8$} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){5-7}
    & & & & $\Delta t_{x}$ & $\Delta t_{y}$ & $\Delta t_{z}$\\
    \midrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]